# Datareader Exception Thrown Database - DateTime

Tags: c#, ms-access

In my Access database I have an AutditLog table which Looks like this

[image: The Log Table]

I simply want to access this table and display each bit of information when Created*(which is the date of the logs) is equal to today's date.
this is my code

```
private void ITemail()
{
     string FinEmail;
     clsDBConnector dbConnector = new clsDBConnector();
     OleDbDataReader dr;
     dbConnector.Connect();
     var sqlStr = " SELECT  Created, [Action], ConnectionLoc, ConnectionSystem, Resource, [Text], RecordId, ToVal, ClientName"
        + "FROM tblAudit WHERE (ClientName = '" + Client + "') AND 'Created' = '" + ToDate() + "'";
     dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr);
     while (dr.Read())
     {
         txtIT.Text = dr[0].ToString() + dr[1].ToString() + dr[2].ToString() + dr[3].ToString() + dr[4].ToString() + dr[5].ToString() + dr[6].ToString()
                + dr[7].ToString() + dr[8].ToString();
     }
}
private string ToDate()
{
    return DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

the problem is that nothing is returned even when i try in server explorer with the correct date as a string nothing is returned. When it reaches the While loop this exception is thrown:

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You should look into parametrized queries. 1) you avoid any chance of sql injection, 2) it handles datatype conversions for you. You would not need to convert a datetime to a string to pass it to a query, where it will either attempt to convert it back to a datetime or implicitly convert the datetime column into a string that may have time included and not match. Also, it looks like you are trying to compare the literal 'Created' = '12/22/2015', which will fail.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the text of some of those exceptions, including the stack trace and any associated error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format and the date delimiter is incorrect and spaces are missing:

```
private void ITemail()
{
     string FinEmail;
     clsDBConnector dbConnector = new clsDBConnector();
     OleDbDataReader dr;
     dbConnector.Connect();
     var sqlStr = "SELECT Created, [Action], ConnectionLoc, ConnectionSystem, Resource, [Text], RecordId, ToVal, ClientName "
        + "FROM tblAudit WHERE (ClientName = '" + Client + "') AND Created = #" + ToDate() + "#";
     dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr);
     while (dr.Read())
     {
         txtIT.Text = dr[0].ToString() + dr[1].ToString() + dr[2].ToString() + dr[3].ToString() + dr[4].ToString() + dr[5].ToString() + dr[6].ToString()
                + dr[7].ToString() + dr[8].ToString();
     }
}
private string ToDate()
{
    return DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
}
```